# my page keeps disappearing when I try to use routes ad route in reacts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to to use Routes and Route and when I do its not showing home.js I get a blank white page.
do I need to download something because it working fine in my other project but I forgot how I did it before.

this is my app.js code

```
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./components/Home.js";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my index.js code

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and tis is Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from './Navbar.js';


const Home = () => {
  const text = "Home";

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{text}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Isn't that the router that is supposed to be inside the App?

Comment: what kind of error are you getting in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did `npm install --save react-router-dom` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't call the router at the right place.

You should try this instead:

```
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./components/Home.js";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also remove the BrowserRouter inside your index

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: I tried it its not working

Comment: Maybe you should remove the exact attribute it’s not used anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `Routes` can only be used as a child of `BrowserRouter`.

Currently, the `Routes` component inside `App.js` is a child of `div`.

2. You can only use `BrowserRouter` once.

A typical approach might be to leave your `index.js` as-is, such that `BrowserRouter` is used once to wrap your entire app, and all your routes live directly below it in `App`, keeping all your routing at the top level.

Inside index.js:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then, in `App.js` return all your routes directly (here `Routes` is a direct child of `BrowserRouter`):

Inside App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

As your app grows in complexity, new routes would be added in `App.js`, but you wouldn't return any JSX, as this isn't allowed. For example, it might look something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path={'/'} element={<Navigation />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='about' element={<About/>} />
        <Route path='shop' element={<Shop/>} />
        <Route path='blog' element={<Blog />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```